# Why don't members like our questions and answers?

Tags: support, voting

**I have noticed very few people up-vote questions or answers in our community.**

**Why?**

**There are lots of metrics on how well a group is doing**

- Visits per day
- Questions per day
- Answers per question

These are all traffic dependent and hard to fix on out own; but, one we can fix is **VOTES**.

The reward system that is baked into Stack Exchange is Reputation and much of Reputation comes from good questions and answers.  This is determined by votes.

I don't think this is working well for our community.  Even the TOP QUESTION often get no votes or at the most just a few - even though they sometimes have over 100 views.

[image: Top 3D questions]

One of the [most viewed questions](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-do-i-give-3d-printed-parts-in-pla-a-shiny-smooth-finish) in our community had **over 3700 views** and had just 34 up votes.  That is better; but, still pretty low compared to both the view count and the response a top question would receive on other communities.

Without up votes, it can be very discouraging to people that put the time and effort into answering questions.  If we want to grow our community, we need to put more effort into hitting the up arrow every time we think that a question or answer was worth the read.  **Remember questions and answers are what fuels the community.  Lets pay our fuel bills.**

Comment: This is true! Votes are also an great tool from separating great questions from those that doesn't make a lot of sense. Personally, I think upvoting generally well thought out questions is a good practice.

Comment: @TormodHaugene, Can you [feature] this post so general users can see it?

Comment: Good idea! It should now be features, I believe. :-)

Comment: With the most recent edit, the title of this question has become quite sensationalist. You can't conclude people "don't like our questions" just because they don't vote much.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden What then can we conclude?  People clearly view the questions and the answers.  An up-vote requires virtually no effort.  Yes, the change in the Subject was intended to draw attention, curiosity, views (and hopefully) responses.